# Saving memory with requests / pandas / StringIO

Tags: pandas, memory, python-requests, stringio

I'm reading a .csv file from the web with `requests` and feeding it via `StringIO` to `pandas.read_csv()`.

The Google Apps Engine gave me a warning about high memory usage so I decided to trace memory allocation with `memory_profiler`:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    44     86.3 MiB     86.3 MiB           1   @profile
    45                                         def forced_load():
    46                                                 '''
    47                                             try:  # if exists locally
    48                                                 db = pd.read_csv('XXX'
    49                                                                  'XXX.csv',
    50                                                                  sep=",", encoding='utf-8')
    51                                             except FileNotFoundError:
    52
    53                                                 '''
    54                                                 # define parameters for a request
    55     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           token = 'XXX'
    56     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           owner = 'XXX'
    57     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           repo = 'XXX'
    58     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           path = 'XXX'
    59     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           filename = 'XXX'
    60
    61                                                 # send a request
    62     91.2 MiB      4.8 MiB           2           r = requests.get(
    63     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/'
    64                                                     f'{owner}/{repo}/master/{path}/{filename}',
    65     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               headers={
    66     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
    67     86.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   'authorization': f'token {token}'
    68                                                             }
    69                                                     )
    70
    71     91.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           r.raise_for_status()
    72
    73                                                 # Load data from text
    74    110.5 MiB     19.4 MiB           1           string_io_obj = StringIO(r.text)
    75    116.7 MiB      6.2 MiB           1           db = pd.read_csv(string_io_obj, sep=",", encoding='utf-8')
    76
    77    116.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           g.last_loaded = monotonic()
    78    116.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return db
```

Sometimes, I get a weird spike in the `requests.get()` and `read_csv()`:

*Case 1* (see lines 62 and 75)

```
    62    134.1 MiB     50.3 MiB           2           r = requests.get(
    63     83.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/'
    64                                                     f'{owner}/{repo}/master/{path}/{filename}',
    65     83.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               headers={
    66     83.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
    67     83.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   'authorization': f'token {token}'
    68                                                             }
    69                                                     )
    70
    71    134.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           r.raise_for_status()
    72
    73                                                 # Load data from text
    74    153.4 MiB     19.4 MiB           1           string_io_obj = StringIO(r.text)
    75    117.9 MiB    -35.5 MiB           1           db = pd.read_csv(string_io_obj, sep=",", encoding='utf-8')
    76
    77    117.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           g.last_loaded = monotonic()
    78    117.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return db
```

*Case 2* (see lines 62 and 75)

```
    62     91.6 MiB     11.3 MiB           2           r = requests.get(
    63     80.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/'
    64                                                     f'{owner}/{repo}/master/{path}/{filename}',
    65     80.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               headers={
    66     80.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
    67     80.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   'authorization': f'token {token}'
    68                                                             }
    69                                                     )
    70
    71     91.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           r.raise_for_status()
    72
    73                                                 # Load data from text
    74    111.0 MiB     19.4 MiB           1           string_io_obj = StringIO(r.text)
    75    166.1 MiB     55.1 MiB           1           db = pd.read_csv(string_io_obj, sep=",", encoding='utf-8')
    76
    77    166.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           g.last_loaded = monotonic()
    78    166.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return db
```

These `requests` and `pandas` spikes come and go, so I don't think if they need to be addressed.

However, I can observe that piping the web response output through `StringIO` (line 74) constantly consumes too much memory.

I can't give a URL to `read_csv()` directly because my web request contains authorization headers. So, I save the response to `StringIO` and then pass it on to `read_csv()`.

I can't write the response contents to a file because the app is running in the Google Apps Engine that uses in-memory disk storage and writing to a temp file would again consume memory.

**Question**: Is there a way to get rid of the 19Mib allocation to StringIO in line 74 or in any other way decrease memory consumption?

Comment: Why not use requests download the file to local, and use pd.read_csv to read the file?

Comment: @Ferris However, it's a Google Apps instance, so the disk resides in memory and writing to a file would again consume memory.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?